# Git commands, reference files by status output index?

Tags: git, alias

Sometimes Git can be rather tedious if there are many similar filenames. For instance:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   FormRegion1.Designer.cs
#       modified:   FormRegion1.cs
#       modified:   FormRegion1.resx
#       modified:   OptionPage.Designer.cs
#       modified:   OptionPage.cs
#       modified:   OptionPage.resx
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I'd much rather type `git diff 1` instead of `git diff FormRegion1.Designer.cs` (even with tab-completion). Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
git diff $( ~/gitstatn 1 )
```

where `~/gitstatn` contains:

```
git status -s | head -n$1 | tail -n1 | cut -c 4-
```

which is no better.

How can I type something like `git add 3` or `git diff 5` and mean `git add FormRegion1.resx` or `git diff OptionPage.cs`, respectively?

I'm using Cygwin on Windows.

.

Edit - As per *adymitruk*'s suggestion, I've settled on aliasing `gpick` to a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo 'no git command specified'
elif [ -z $2 ]; then
    git $1
else
    git $1 $( git ls-files -m | head -n$2 | tail -n1 )
fi
```

which is sufficient for my needs.

Comment: I would just use copy and paste.

Comment: Wait, so you'd rather memorize the ordinal number of a file in a file listing output that you're not even looking at (presumably re-memorizing it when a new file comes along and changes the order of things) than to use tab-completion to actually call the file by its name?

Comment: @Dan: No, I'd rather say `git status` followed by `git diff x`. Tab-completion is more tedious IMO, especially on a case-sensitive system with long, similar filenames. This might be a niche thing, but I find it to be quite valuable for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use git ls-files instead. You won't need cut. You will need to script. You could use the -p parameter for add, but I like your script. make the script accept the command you want:

```
gpick diff 1
gpick add 3
```

You may want to do something for untracked files too.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check out [git-number](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number). <plug>I wrote it specifically for this use case</plug>.